# Unity error after trying to build a WebGL bundle

Tags: unity-game-engine, webgl, game-engine, unity-webgl

As you can see from the image below, Unity keeps throwing out this error. I really don't know why it is not working. I have tried doing a clean build twice. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Unity Error Message]

Comment: Would also like to mention that I have tried disabled compression and I have also tried changing it to gzip, however I still receive the same error.

Comment: How are you running it? Did you configure the webserver as Unity explain? Did you upload all the files?

Comment: I got it to work by clicking build and run rather than just build. Thank you.